# Downloading .mp3 file from the server and load in MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to download a .mp3 file from the localhost server, but the only problem I think is the directory that I am downloading to. Code is not giving any errors but in `if(file.Exists())` is always returning false, it seems that the file is not properly downloaded.

Downloading the file:

```
 if (isConnectedToInternet())
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                int numberFile = 1;
                ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity);
                pd.SetCancelable(true);
                pd.SetMessage("Pleasy wait for files to be downloaded... 0/16");
                pd.Show();
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, s) => {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Download file completed.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                };
                try
                {


                        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, s) => {
                            if (numberFile == 1)
                            {
                                pd.Cancel();
                            }
                        };

                        string appDataDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                        string filePath = soundListViewAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).path1;
                        if (!Directory.Exists(appDataDir))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataDir);
                        }

                        //I have to do .Remove(0,1) because filePath starts with the '/'

                        string path = Path.Combine(appDataDir, filePath.Remove(0, 1));

                        Toast.MakeText(Activity, path, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        System.Uri url = new System.Uri(server + "rpad/api" + soundListViewAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).path1);
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(url, path);


                }
                catch
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Files are not downloaded", ToastLength.Long);
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "No connection", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

Loading the file:

```
m1 = new MediaPlayer();

            string appDataDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string filePath = prefs.GetString("path1", "empty");
            string path = Path.Combine(appDataDir, filePath.Remove(0, 1));
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
            if (file.Exists())
            {
                FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                m1.SetDataSource(fileStream.FD);
                m1.Prepare();
                m1.Start();
            }
```

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataDir);`. Check the return value as it might fail to create a directory. In that case display a toast to the user saying so. And return. Do not continue with the code as it does not make sense to download a file to a non existing directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code is not giving any errors but in if(file.Exists()) is always returning false, it seems that the file is not properly downloaded.

By `Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);`, you are only creating a `File` instance. The file hasn't been created on the device. You need to call [`File.CreateNewFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) to create this file, and before that, make sure all the parent folders are created by using `Directory.CreateDirectory`:

```
string appDataDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string filePath = "Test/empty/abc.txt";
string parentPath = Path.Combine(appDataDir, "Test/empty");
string path = Path.Combine(appDataDir, filePath);
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
Directory.CreateDirectory(parentPath);//make sure the parent directory is created
file.CreateNewFile();//create the file
if (file.Exists())
{
  ...
}
```